# Deserialize into Map<String, String> with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "parameters": [{
      "value": "somevalue",
      "key": "somekey"
    },
    {
      "value": "othervalue",
      "key": "otherkey"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that the contract of this response guarantees that keys are unique.

I would like to deseralize this into the following class:

```
public class Response {

  public Map<String, String> parameters;

}
```

How can i do this using the Jackson library?

Comment: probably not at all, that is not what a "map" would look like in json. That is an Array of KeyValuePairs.

Comment: Well, a map is an array of key-value pairs, where the keys are distinct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to register a deserializer:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(Response.class, new ResponseDeserializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);

Response resp = mapper.readValue(myjson, Response.class);
```

Here is an example:

```
public class ResponseDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Response> {
    public ResponseDeserializer() { 
        this(null); 
    } 

    public ResponseDeserializer(Class<?> vc) { 
        super(vc); 
    }

    @Override
    public Response deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext dc)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        Response resp = new Response();
        resp.parameters = new HashMap<>();
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        ArrayNode parms = (ArrayNode)node.get("parameters");
        for (JsonNode parm: parms) {
            String key = parm.get("key").asText();
            String value = parm.get("value").asText();
            resp.parameters.put(key, value);
        }
        return resp;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you change your JSON to the following?

```
{
  "parameters": {
      "somekey": "somevalue",
      "otherkey" : "othervalue"
  }
}
```

If so, deserialization should work without any custom deserializer.

(Reference: https://blog.hackingcode.io/jackson-java-tutorial-deserialize-json-to-map/ )

Comment: Unfortunately not, but i solved it using a custom deserializer.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a [custom deserializer](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization) for this.

Comment: Thanks, but posting a generic link is not really helpful. :)

Comment: Sure it is. Just read the article and try some code. If you are stuck, you can post the code in a new question...

Comment: I have to agree with @Fortega that it sort of does, take a look at "3. Custom Deserializer on ObjectMapper" of that article

Comment: See [answer] about **Provide context for links**, a link can die, so it is safer to add at least the interesting part of the linked page.